# Mongoose populate sorting not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While i was debugging issue, i found, that mongoose sorting not working correctly. I removed our code and made simple test. You can run it see that it will fail.

Maybe someone seen it before? Maybe i am missing something?

thank you for your assistance!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');

mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);

var CarsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    car: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Car'
    },
    quantity: Number
});

var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    suborders: [CarsSchema]
});
mongoose.model('Cars', OrderSchema);

var Car = mongoose.model('Car');
var Cars = mongoose.model('Cars');

Car.create([
    {
        name: 'Tesla'
    },
    {
        name: 'BMW'
    }
], function (err, objs) {

    Cars.create({
        suborders: [
            {
                car: objs[1]._id, //BMW
                quantity: 1
            }, {
                car: objs[0]._id, //Tesla
                quantity: 2
            }
        ]
    }, function (err, order) {

        Cars.findById(order._id)
            .populate({
                path: 'suborders.car',
                options: {
                    sort: '-name'
                }
            }).exec(function (err, cars) {

            assert.equal(cars.suborders[0].car.name, 'Tesla', 'DESC: 0 should be Tesla');
            assert.equal(cars.suborders[1].car.name, 'BMW', 'DESC: 1 should be BMW');

            assert.equal(cars.suborders[0].quantity, 2, 'DESC: Tesla quantity should be 2');
            assert.equal(cars.suborders[1].quantity, 1, 'DESC: BMW quantity should be 1');

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confirmed mongoose bug [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202), and said not easy to fix. :(

The key phenomena is first two assertions passed, then failed in the third assertion.

Maybe you can change schema design or search for something like 'mongoose subdocuments sorting'. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932690/how-to-sort-select-and-query-subdocument-in-mongoose) is an example applying `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you cannot sort populated fields in mongooose/mongodb. Indeed the populated fields are here virtually present, made possible by mongoose. But they are not present in the actual database (since mongo does not support joins), and that is where the sort is actually applied.

So you'll have to sort the result array manually, by using javascript builtin function Array.sort(compare) or any of your prefered required modules.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it may be helpful for you because In mongoose populate options
>   provide the correct sort order

```
  Cars.findById(order._id)
                .populate({
                    path: 'suborders.car',
                    options: {
                        sort: {name:-1}
                    }
                }).exec(function (err, cars) {
});
```

Comment: Amazing !! all I needed to do is wrap it with `options` and boom sorted!